# Up to what point $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-2})$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For example, I have:  $x^2=y^2+2b^2$ ;  b,x,y integers, (x,y)=1 and x,y odd.

Then:  $x^2=(y+b\sqrt{-2})(y-b\sqrt{-2})$ .

In  $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-2})$ :  $x\nmid (y\pm b\sqrt{-2})$ .  Because:  $\dfrac{y}{x}\pm\dfrac{b}{x}\,\sqrt{-2}\,\notin\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-2})$ .

Does it mean that  $x\nmid y^2+2b^2$  in  $\mathbb{Z}$  because  $\mathbb{Z}$  is a subring of  $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-2})$ ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: @LukasRollier Thanks a lot Lukas

Comment: @LukasRollier. Sorry Lukas, but going over this, Ive noticed that:  $9^2=7^2+2\cdot 4^2$ .  Something in the theory is wrong..

Comment: @LukasRollier. I get it, the example works because:  $9=1+2\cdot 4$ .  And then:  $9=(1+2\sqrt{-2})(1-2\sqrt{-2})$ ..